# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in

Tags: sql, database, syntax

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/orientsolutionsc/public_html/cdmdb/dbcon.php on line 19

Here Is My Codes

```
//Insert data into `mysql` 

$sql="INSERT INTO users(jimbo, kata, mtaa ,uongozi )
VALUES('$jimbo', '$kata', '$mtaa' '$uongozi')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Should study your programming error before post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(jimbo, kata, mtaa ,uongozi )
VALUES('".$jimbo."', '".$kata."', '".$mtaa."', '".$uongozi."')"
```

Or if you want to insert `'$jimbo'` etc.. as a string then

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(jimbo, kata, mtaa ,uongozi )
VALUES('$jimbo', '$kata', '$mtaa', '$uongozi')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed (,) comma between `'$mtaa' '$uongozi'`

```
VALUES('$jimbo', '$kata', '$mtaa', '$uongozi')";
```